# Redux performance in a large scale JS app

Tags: redux, redux-framework

I recently started studying redux, after few hours i got the question in my mind about performance of redux in a large scale web application.

my question is since redux maintains the previous states of the store over time, let's say the application is big enough and having ample amount of state changes over the time, doesn't it reduce the performance of the app since of the increasing memory consumption over time to maintain all the previous states?

FYI : i'm thinking based on java background of garbage collection and releasing the unused memory after some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you use immutable data structures like the ones provided by [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/), there is no extra cost to remembering the previous states when adding or updating an existing data structure other than keeping track of references. This is one of the big advantages of using immutable data structures. Of course, when a state change consists of replacing the complete state with something else, these advantages are mitigated.

That said, you don't *have* to keep track of the previous states, it's just much easier and more effective to do it with immutable data structures.

Also, Redux doesn't remember previous states by default, this is only used  in the redux devtools which provides the "time travel" functionality you seem to aim at. This is very handy during development.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing my doubts, i saw about immutable.js but didn't went on and dug deeper in to it and its advantages. well now i have clear directions and clear understanding from  your answer.Thanks again.

Comment: Just for clarity, you don't need immutable.js if you just want to work with default javascript objects and arrays. You just need to make sure you always create new values in your reducers. For objects you could do this with Object.assign and for arrays you could use something like the ES6 array spread operator.

Comment: i did some samples using the methods you mentioned, Object.assign and the spread operator. i had doubts mainly on performance thanks for clearing that out :) although as you mentioned would like to do some examples with immutable and try out the things out of curiosity of trying it too :)